# Use of Combobox to populate cell with functions and external links

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

It is very simple but yet I can't figure it out. Maybe because it cannot be done? Regardless here we go:

I would like to use a combobox that will, when selected, input cells with text values, functions and reference to external cells.

First line of the options would be to have the name populated.

Second line is a formula that would change from course to course.

Third line would provide a cell with a reference to another cell's content from another file. So if multiple course file are used I can have one master file that if I change the content of a cell the change will reflect on all the course file cells that are referring to it once updated.

This is in crude code form what I would like it to perform.

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "ITCourse" Then
    Worksheets("PARADE STATE").Range("I1").Value = "ITCourse"
    Worksheets("Data Base").Range("C1").Value = IF(V9>70,"Prep Week",IF(V9>65,"Week 1",IF(V9>60,"Week 2",IF(V9>55,"Week 3",IF(V9>50,"Week 4",IF(V9>45,"Week 5",IF(V9>40,"Week 6",IF(V9>35,"Week 7",IF(V9>30,"Week 8",IF(V9>25,"Week 9",IF(V9>20,"Week 10",IF(V9>15,"Week 11",IF(V9>10,"Week 12",IF(V9>5,"Week 13",IF(V9>0,"Week 14")))))))))))))))
    Worksheets("Week 1").Range("B2").Value = 'N:\ITcourse\00 - Data Base\[ITcourse.xlsx]Sheet'!$A$3
End If
If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "HRCourse" Then
    Worksheets("PARADE STATE").Range("I1").Value = "HRCourse"
    Worksheets("Data Base").Range("C1").Value = IF(V9>40,"Prep Week",IF(V9>35,"Week 1",IF(V9>30,"Week 2",IF(V9>25,"Week 3",IF(V9>20,"Week 4",IF(V9>15,"Week 5",IF(V9>10,"Week 6",IF(V9>5,"Week 7",IF(V9>5,"Week 8")))))))))
    Worksheets("Week 1").Range("B2").Value = 'N:\ITcourse\00 - Data Base\[HRcourse.xlsx]Sheet'!$A$3
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is the first line functioning properly? I suspect the second line isn't doing what you want.  You're setting a cell `Value`, but you want instead [to set a `.Formula`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx)

Comment: I knew it was simple. So yes the first line works. And now the second line works as long as you format it this way: Worksheets("Data Base").Range("C1").Value = "IF(V9>70,""Prep Week"",IF(V9>65,""Week 1""........)))" as long as you put double "" every time you need to have one after your opening one then close the line with ". The third line works as well.

Comment: So to expend on what I'm doing with those formula. I was using one spread sheet per course type but most of the stats that were compile were the same so I wanted to only have one spread sheet that does all course types. Once the course type is selected it will change formulas and fetch cells according to the selection. Within the spread sheet I have a week by week agenda of task to do and have a master spread sheet that I make changes to that are now reflected to all the courses of the same type. We run about 9 course at a time out of 5 different types.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function that returns the number of weeks for any given course name. This function should use a `Dictionary` to store the information, and the dictionary may be loaded from a dedicated worksheet.

```
Function WeeksPerCourse(courseName As String) As Long
    Static dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    If dict Is Nothing Then
        ' Fill the dictionary here. Note that it is better
        ' to load the values from a dedicated, hidden worksheet
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dict("ITCourse") = 14
        dict("HRCourse") = 8
        ' Etc...
    End If
    WeeksPerCourse = dict(courseName)
End Function
```

With this function available, your procedure can be simplified like follows:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim course As Sting: course = Trim(ComboBox1.value)
    Worksheets("PARADE STATE").Range("I1").value = course

    'Dim nWeek As Long
    'nWeek = WeeksPerCourse(course) - Worksheets("PARADE STATE").Range("V9").value / 5
    'Worksheets("Data Base").Range("C1").value = IIf(nWeek < 1, "Prep Week", "Week " & nWeek)

    Worksheets("Data Base").Range("C1").Formula = "= ""Week "" & INT((WeeksPerCourse('PARADE STATE'!I1) - 'PARADE STATE'!V9)/5)"

    Worksheets("Week 1").Range("B2").Formula= "='N:\ITcourse\00 - Data Base\[" & course & ".xlsx]Sheet'!$A$3"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is understood what I'm trying to do with the function. The function works I just want it to populate in a specific cell when I change the value of the Combobox as it changes according to the course. The function is using V9 to see how many days are left until the course end date. Then the function uses this value to figure out what week you are on today.

Comment: @NicolasCardin-Lemay Well I couldn't tell that your second line was to be a formula instead of a value. anyway I changed the code to reflect that, It will use `WeeksPerCourse` as a UDF. Only thing is for now it should display "Week 0" instead of "Prep Week"; we can eventually change it if we verify that the idea fits your need. Note that the formula can be static since it updates automatically when `I1` and `V9` change. that means you can enter it directly to excel and you dont need to update it when combo selection changes.